# How to expand a div to browser height or width whilst keeping in it proportion? [DIAGRAM INSIDE]

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios, responsive-design

If the browser window is shrunk then I want the div and the image inside it to shrink too. But it has to stay in the middle and always stay the same proportions. Is this possible? I have been trying for ages without luck. I'm open to using jQuery or JS if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like this (using jQuery):

```
<script language="jscript">
    $(function(){
        ratio=$('#centerdiv').width()/$('#centerdiv').height();
        rePos=function(){
            if($('#container').innerHeight()*ratio>$('#container').innerWidth()){
                $('#centerdiv').width($('#container').innerWidth());
                $('#centerdiv').height($('#centerdiv').width()/ratio);
                $('#centerdiv').offset({left:0,top:($('#container').innerHeight()-$('#centerdiv').outerHeight(true))/2});
            }
            else{
                $('#centerdiv').height($('#container').innerHeight());
                $('#centerdiv').width($('#centerdiv').height()*ratio);
                $('#centerdiv').offset({left:($('#container').innerWidth()-$('#centerdiv').outerWidth(true))/2,top:0});
            }
        };
        $(window).resize(rePos);
        rePos();
    });
    </script>
    <div id="container" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0">
    <div id="centerdiv" style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:100px;background-color:red;padding:0;border:0;margin:0"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you do $(window).resize(function(){resPos();}); instead of $(windows).resize(resPos); ?

Comment: $(windows).resize(resPos); is better.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be something like

**HTML** head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and the body:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="whatever.jpg"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

and **CSS**:

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 480px; 
  background: #900;
  margin: 1em auto;    
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;    
}
```

Basically, the container div takes up 90% of the available width, up to a maximum of 480px, and the img within the container takes up all the space available to it, resizing accordingly. Obviously all of the particulars there are arbitrary and would depend entirely on your particular design. I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/QjQge/embedded/result/) where you can see it in action.

**Edit**: forgot the viewport meta tag which keeps things kosher on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks. That works when resizing horizontally, but it doesn't work when the browser is vertically resized. Is there a way it can be done vertically too?